# Como Recupero las bases de datos de servidor anterior en WAMPSERVER?

Tags: wampserver

Venia trabajando con wampserver 3.1 e instale la version 3.2 sin desinstalar la 3.1 esto quiere decir que el directorio de la version anaterior sigue ahi.

Todos los proyectos estaban en un VirtualHost de tal manera que no fue sino crear el VirtualHost de nuevo en la nueva version ahi estaban, pero las bases de datos ya no se ven en el phpMyAdmin.

Como recupero las bases de datos MySql?